# Keep the fading in between the border-top and border-bottom in css

Tags: css, frontend, gradient, linear-gradients, fading

I am trying to get a fade on the post content, just like the title. See image. [image]

However, I can't manage to make it sit in between the top and bottom border.Here is the code.

This is the post Message container.

```
.PostMessage{
max-height: 6em;
overflow:hidden;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is the fading.

```
.PostMessage::before{
position:absolute;
content: '';
background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 93%, red 99%);
width: calc(100% - 61px);
max-width: 728px;
height: 97px;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="PostContainer">

        <div class="PostContainerMetadata">
            <p class="PostContainerMetadataID">Post id # <a href="">23</a></p>
            <p class="PostContainerMetadataInfo"> <a href="">Videogames</a> • Posted by <a href="">user</a> on xx-xx-xx</p>
        </div>

        <div class="PostTitle">
            <h2>Title of post</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="PostMessage"><pre><code>This is a short message.</code></pre></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: `.PostMessage` has a flexible height with a `max-height` of `6em` whereas its `::before` pseudo-element has a static height of `97px`, which makes the `::before` taller than the element itself. You'd need to find a way to keep them of identical height.

Comment: @BumhanYu Yeah, tha's what I am trying to find, a way to keep them the same height.

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR. Replace fixed height with a flexible one. (See code snippet)

As noted in the comment, `.PostMessage` has a flexible height with a `max-height` of `6em` whereas its `::before` pseudo-element has a static height of `97px`, which makes the `::before` taller than the element itself.

You can add `position: relative` to the main `.PostMessage` element, and use `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` for its `::before` pseudo-elements, and remove `height` of it.

```css
.PostMessage {
  max-height: 6em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.PostMessage::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 93%, red 99%);
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="PostMessage">
  short message
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="PostMessage">
  longer message <br /> spanning over <br /> multiple lines <br /> here <br /> .
  <br /> .
  <br /> .
  <br /> .
  <br /> .
  <br /> .
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Wow thank you very much! That works well but now it won't align where it needs to be. In my first screenshot the fade sits at the limit, where the green line is in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/MLdGoWN.png

Comment: Just edited the answer to replace `width` with `left: 0;` and `right: 0`, which can be adjusted to your needs. Not knowing what your nested HTML markups look like, I cannot be 100% certain where it falls though.

Comment: Yeah I figured it might be troublesome if I didn't include the HTML. I just edited my original post to include it. Sadly including the left and right attributes didn't work in my case. Thank you very much for your help anyways! Maybe I can find some workaround myself now that you taught me how to do it.